# I can't get my drop down menu to work

Tags: javascript

I want for people to hide/show `nav` when they click "Menu". Here is my code:

```
<script>
    document.querySelector(".switch").onclick = function() {
        if (document.querySelector(".mobileNav ul").className == "drop"){
            this.className = "dropShow";
        }
        else {
            this.className = "drop";
        }
    };

</script>
```

but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: so what is wrong with it?

Comment: It doesn't do anything

Comment: Should it work the way it is?

Comment: I edited your question so that it is marked with `javascript` tag. Please apply this change.

Comment: ok, I did it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. Just a minor error.

**this.className** assigns the className to the button element with class *.switch*.
Instead do the following:

```
document.querySelector(".switch").onclick = function() {

    var ulElem = document.querySelector(".mobileNav ul");

    if ( ulElem.className== "drop"){
        ulElem.className = "dropShow";
    }
    else {
        ulElem.className = "drop";
    }
};
```

Comment: happy to help..:)